# apply chi-square test in R for each level of a categorical variable

Tags: r

I'm having a  data frame as below. I want to run a chi-square test between 'placement' and 'books_quantile' variables at each level of zip codes. I've tried a few ways but not successful yet. Can somebody help?

Thank you!

```
str(zip2)
tibble [10,748 x 3] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ placement     : Factor w/ 5 levels "3 or More Grade Levels Below",..: 5 3 3 3 5 2 2 5 3 5 ...
 $ books_quantile: Factor w/ 4 levels "Q1 (>=56 books)",..: 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 2 1 2 ...
 $ zip           : Factor w/ 24 levels "38016","38018",..: 11 21 9 8 22 12 15 15 13 12 ...
```

Comment: The simplest way is to make a 3d array: `zip2.arr <- xtabs(~placement + books_quantile + zip, zip2)`. Then you can generate all of the chi square results into a list with `zip2.chi <- lapply(1:24, function(i) chisq.test(zip2.arr[ , , i]))`. Finally name the list parts with `names(zip2.chi) <- levels(zip2$zip)`. You can access the results with `zip2.chi[[1]]` or `zip2.chi[["38016"]]`.

Comment: `apply(xtabs(~.+zip, zip2), 3, chisq.test)` should do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do:

```
apply(xtabs(~placement + books_quantile + zip, zip2), 3, chisq.test)
```